# Compatibilidad con Safari en Ipad y Iphone

Tags: jquery, ajax, iphone, safari

Buenas tardes, estoy realizando un formulario que envío un correo y almacena los datos en una base de datos. Se ejecuta correctamente en Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge y Safari (pero este ultimo solamente en la version de sobremesa, la inserción en la base de datos no se produce cuando se realiza el proceso desde un Ipad o un Iphone). Adjunto el fragmento que se encarga de la inserción en la base de datos.

```
function envioMensaje()
{


      $('#Formulario').on("click",'#solicitar', function(ev) {                    
      ev.preventDefault();


      var datos={
                  "nombre": $('#nombre').val(),
                  "telefono": $('#Telefono').val(),
                  "mail": $('#mail').val(),
                  "producto": $(':selected').val(),
                  "extraInfo": $('#otrosArticulos').val()
                  }
      var datosMensajes={
                  "nombre": $('#nombre').val(),
                  "telefono": $('#Telefono').val(),
                  "mail": $('#mail').val(),
                  "producto": $('#producto option:selected').text(),
                  "extraInfo": $('#otrosArticulos').val()
                  }


  var mensaje = "envioMensajes.php";                
  var urlEnvio = "Proceso que ejecuta la insercion, la he eliminado por cuestion de privacidad".
             $.ajax({
                type:"post",  
                url:urlEnvio, //Para registro sin mensaje
                jsonp: "callback",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data:datos
                //success: mensaje
           });
           $.ajax({
                type:"post",  
                url:mensaje, //Para mensaje
                jsonp: "callback",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data:datosMensajes,
                success: function(data){

                } 
           }); 
    }); window.location.href = "index_gracias.php#free-h";
};
```

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Añado la parte del codigo que recoge los datos.

```
<form id="Formulario" name="formucontacto">
              <div class="center">
              <div id="free-h">
                 <h3>Pide tu demo <strong>Gratuita!</strong></h3>
                <span><img src="images/icon-tlf.png" alt="Teléfono" width="24" height="34" align="absmiddle"/><a href="tel:+665458897">+665458897</a></span>
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" id='nombre' name="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre..." required>
                    <input id='mail' name="mail" type = 'email' placeholder="Introduce tu correo electrónico" required>
                    <input id='Telefono' name="telefono" type = 'text' placeholder="Introduce tu telefono" required>
                    <select id="producto" required>
                        <option value="" default>-- Selecciona tu producto --</option>
                        <option value="1">Producto1</option>
                        <option value="2">Producto2</option>
                        <option value="3">Producto3</option>
                        <option value="4">Producto4</option>
                        <option value="5">Producto5</option>
                        <option value="6">Otro...</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="legal">
                        <input name="condiciones" id='Condiciones' type="checkbox" required>Acepto la
                            <a style="color:#aaa; overflow:auto; text-decoration:underline;" onclick="window.open(this.href, this.target, 'width=400,height=720'); return false;" target="_blank" href="nota.html">política de privacidad.</a>

                      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfM6h8UAAAAAAGzSXe_abDnV3slmQdVOsO2elXz" data-callback="enableBtn"></div> 

                    <!--      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Aqui va la clave de recaptcha Google" data-callback="enableBtn"></div> -->
                    </span>

                   <input type="submit" onClick = 'validarcontacto()' id="solicitar" value="SOLICITAR" disabled />                    
                </form>
```

Basicamente, al validar el Captcha es cuando el boton de SOLICITAR se habilita, y al pulsar sobre este se realiza la validacion de los campos, y posteriormente el envio de los datos.

Comment: Revisa si no tienes Javascript desactivado en el Safari que no está funcionando.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo he comprobado, tanto en el telefono como en el Ipad se encuentran activado.

Comment: ¿Puedes probar si [este fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g38peLvo/) funciona desde el iPad/iPhone?

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de comprobarlo desde el IPad, y funciona el segundo y el tercero, pero no el primero.

Comment: He leído eso: que para hacerlo funcionar tienes que ponerle un identificador CSS al elemento o modificar la forma de llamar el on.click entonces tendrías que adaptar tu código a una de las dos formas que funcionan y funcionará. Más tarde podría quizá elaborar una respuesta ya que ahora estoy ocupado. En el fiddle tienes el ejemplo de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por la ayuda, intentare hacerlo ahora y te aviso con lo que sea :)

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de intentar con ambas opciones, pero no logro hacerlas funcionar, no se si no he llegado a entenderlo bien por completo por lo que agradecería cuando pudieras el ejemplo que me has comentado. Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hay una [pregunta parecida en el sitio en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881509/jquery-on-doesnt-work-with-mobile-safari). Parece que Safari en móvil puede tener algún bug o algo. Prueba a poner `onclick=""` en el elemento `#solicitar` para ver si así te funciona, también dicen de usar `document` como selector en lugar de un id. [EDIT] acabo de ver que es lo que @A.Cedano usa en el JSFiddle y que te funciona.

Comment: Por favor pon en la pregunta el HTML del elemento desde el cual llamas las funciones de jQuery.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro he encontrado la doc de MDN que refiere en efecto que se trata de un bug de Safari (ver respuesta más abajo).

Answer (score 3):

Esto ocurre debido a un bug de [safari](/questions/tagged/safari) que ha sido [reportado por MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile):

> Safari Mobile 7.0+ (y probablemente versiones anteriores también)
>   sufre de **un error en el que los eventos de clic no se disparan en
>   elementos que no son típicamente interactivos** (por ejemplo, ) y
>   que tampoco tienen oidores de eventos directamente conectados a los
>   elementos (Es decir, se está utilizando la delegación de eventos).
>   [Vea este ejemplo en vivo para una demostración](http://jsfiddle.net/cvrhulu/k9t0sdnf/show/). Consulte también
>   [Documentos de Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW6) para hacer que los elementos se puedan hacer
>   clic y la [definición de "elemento que se puede hacer clic"](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7).

---

### Soluciones conocidas para este error:

- Establecer `cursor: pointer;` En el elemento o cualquiera de sus ancestros.
- Agregue un atributo dummy `onclick="void (0)"` al elemento o cualquiera de sus ancestros de más arriba, pero sin incluir `<body>`.
- Utilice un elemento típicamente interactivo (por ejemplo, `<a>`) en lugar de uno que no sea típicamente interactivo (por ejemplo, `<div>`).
- Deje de usar la [delegación de eventos de clic](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Safari Mobile considera que los siguientes elementos son típicamente interactivos (y por lo tanto no se ven afectados por este error):

- `<a>` (pero debe tener un href)
- `<area>` (pero debe tener un href)
- `<button>`
- `<img>`
- `<input>`
- `<label>` (pero debe estar asociado con un control de formulario)
- `<textarea>`

*Esta lista es incompleta; Usted puede ayudar a MDN haciendo más pruebas / investigación y expandiéndolo.*

---

### Propuesta de solución

En base a lo dicho anteriormente, te muestro una posible solución. No obstante, puedes optar por otra de las mencionadas más arriba si así lo prefieres.

Cambia tu función de llamada de esta manera:

- Agregando un nombre de clase al input que quieres escuchar desde jQuery, aquí la he llamado `ios`
- Lanzando el evento `on.click` en base a esa clase y no al id del elemento

**Nota:** He tomado sólo algunas partes del formulario y quitado las condiciones required... he obviado también lo del CAPTCHA. Lo único importante es que se ha agregado el elemento `class` al input en cuestión y que se cambia la forma del `on.click`

Pruébalo en todas las terminales y dime si funciona.

```js
$(function() {

  function validarContacto() {
    alert("click válido para todos, iOS incluido");
  }
  $("input.ios").on("click", validarContacto);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="Formulario" name="formucontacto">
  <div class="center">
    <div id="free-h">
      <h3>Pide tu demo <strong>Gratuita!</strong></h3>
      <span><img src="images/icon-tlf.png" alt="Teléfono" width="24" height="34" align="absmiddle"/><a href="tel:+665458897">+665458897</a></span>
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id='nombre' name="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre...">
        <input id='mail' name="mail" type='email' placeholder="Introduce tu correo electrónico">
        <input id='Telefono' name="telefono" type='text' placeholder="Introduce tu telefono">


        <input type="submit" onClick='validarcontacto()' id="solicitar" value="SOLICITAR" class='ios' />
</form>
```

**PD:** Probado en iPad y en Desktop y funciona en ambos.

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicacion, ahora mismo no puedo probarlo porque todos los dispositivos ipad que hay son de la empresa donde trabajo y ya he salido, pero mañana nada mas llegar lo pruebo y te comento, y ante todo, muchas gracias por el ejemplo y la explicación tan detallada que me has dado.

Comment: @AntonioMP87 De nada. Lo he probado en iPad y funciona. Saludos y espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: @AntonioMP87 ¿qué pasó finalmente con esto?

Comment: Esta respuesta esta brutal, merece mas puntos, +1.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso no me funciona - en *ipad* y me imagino que *safari* en general. Dentro de la función uso `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : $(this).attr('data-order'),
            success:function(response){
                $('#cookies').html(response);
            }
        })
```

La llamada se hace a través de un `button`.