# ¿Como hacer funcionar onclick en tableta iPhone y movil iPhone?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hola tengo un problema con la función onclick en tableta Ipad y móvil Ipad,

capturo el id de un producto por medio de php y lo envió como parámetro a una función llamada addCar, esto funciona bien para pc de escritorio y celulares android pero no es así en ipod, este es mi botón donde capturo el evento:

```
   <button type="button" onclick="addCar('<?=$product->prod_id;?>'),saltar()" class="btn btn-success">agregar</button>
```

y esta es la función que recibe el id del producto, todo funciona bien, el problema esta al momento de abrir el sistema web en un Ipod movil o tablet no hace la acción de agregara a carrito este es mi código de la función:

```
function addCar(id_producto){

    var id1 = id_producto;

    if(id1 == "") {

      }else {

        $.post(base_url+'Carrito/add_item',{
          id:id1,
            beforeSend:function(){
              saltar();
            console.log("agregando elemento");
            }
        },function(respuesta){

          $("#carrito").load(" #carrito").fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);

            // Override global options
              toastr.success('Agregaste producto a carrito <i class="fas fa-share"></i>', '¡Bien hecho!', {timeOut: 1000})
            // toastr.success('Agregaste producto a carrito!')

        });
      }
}
```

Comment: Como me gustaria tener esa cantidad de dinero :'v.

Comment: Creo que se debe al explorador por defecto que usa ios, el cual si no estoy mal es safari, creo que hay cosas que en ese explorador no van bien, intenta lo mismo pero en otro navegador web, por ejemplo mozilla o chrome si es que estan disponibles para ios, si funciona con esos navegadores el problema es de safari.

Comment: Incluso puede ser que `jQuery` no este funcionando bien en safari, pero creo que es poco posible.

Comment: Este fragmento de código aparentemente es valido, yo apostaría por alguna otra parte de tu código, recuerda que se ejecuta en cascada y un error impide que se ejecute correctamente el resto....

Si tienes un iPhone y una Mac puedes usar la depuración remota., safari incluye esa función muy similar a la de Chrome con android

Comment: @ArturoGallegos si ese es el caso, no explica el porque el mismo código en otras plataformas si funciona bien, de todas maneras si que es buena idea que el `OP` nos provea de mas informacion, puesto que el otro posible error puede ser que enrealidad hayan funciones nativas o metodos que el OP este usando y que en safari no existen o no son compatibles.

Comment: @Riven como tu mismo ya has dicho en comentarios anteriores, cada navegador tiene sus propias capacidades y deficiencias, Safari es bastante especial, al desconocer el resto de su código es mucho adivinar y especular, la mejor opción en estos casos es usar la depuración remota, al menos lo ha sido para mi., aunque no siempre se tenga acceso a estos dispositivos.... igual si comparte mas código quizás veamos algún detalle

Comment: Uffff totalmente de acuerdo, la depuracion remota es magnifica en estos casos!, a mi me ayudo con `MediaDevices`, el cual me di cuenta que no me funcionaba en el movil no por el explorador, si no por temas de seguridad, mientras que en el PC si me funcionaba, y era por algo bastante estupido pero a la vez importante.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Compatibilidad con Safari en Ipad y Iphone](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68272/compatibilidad-con-safari-en-ipad-y-iphone)